# How to install a replacement lock in a mailbox?

Tags: lock

How do I install this lock in my mail box?

[image]
[image]

Where do I twist/turn/rotate/pull to separate the thick front part from the end part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the hex nut. Insert the lock. Replace the hex nut.

You'll probably need to use the key to hold the assembly while you loosen the nut, but it shouldn't be too tight. If it is for some reason, maybe use a large flat-blade screwdriver and just insert it a bit into the keyslot. In a worst-case scenario, put a wrench or pliers sideways on the lock latch and hold it that way.

Comment: The hex nut is the thick hexagon after the cone where you insert the key?

Comment: Yepper. It looks like... a nut. :)

Comment: You may need to dismount the tailpiece (the arm that swings to lock the door). It is probably just held on by a screw, though other fasteners sre sometimes used.

Comment: This tailpiece looks like it's held on by a black snap-ring rather than a screw, though I've seen plenty that are just press-fit and can't be removed.

Comment: Looks like the nut is large enough to slide over the tailpiece; note the significant reduction in the barrel diameter past the threads for the nut.

Comment: It is large enough, yes